# loop button and callback creation with kivy

Tags: python, for-loop, button, callback, kivy

can someone tell me how I can create multiple button with a different callback for each in python kivy ? Because when I run this, it's always the same callback that is call.

```
material_list = ["IRON", "COPPER", "ZINC"]
l_button_pressed = []

class Button_Widget(Widget):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    super(Button_Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    for i in range(len(material_list)):
        btn = Button(text=material_list[i-1],
                     font_size="15sp",
                     background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     pos=(100, 355-105*(i-1)))
        btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.add_widget(btn)
```

Here are the callback to my buttons that I will loop in the futur.

```
def callback(self, instance):
    if "Iron" in l_button_pressed:
        pass
    else:
        if len(l_button_pressed) == 0:
            self.iron = TextInput(text="",
                                  pos=(350, 250),
                                  background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                                  size = (100, 48))
            ironlbl = Label(text="IRON",
                            size = (100, 48),
                            pos = (350, 300),
                            color = (255, 255, 255, 1),
                            font_size="15sp")
        else:
            self.iron = TextInput(text="",
                                  pos=(500, 250),
                                  background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                                  size = (100, 48))
            ironlbl = Label(text="IRON",
                            size=(100, 48),
                            pos=(500, 300),
                            color=(255, 255, 255, 1),
                            font_size="15sp")
        self.add_widget(ironlbl)
        self.add_widget(self.iron)
        l_button_pressed.extend(["Iron"])

def callback2(self, instance):
    if "Copper" in l_button_pressed:
        pass
    else:
        if len(l_button_pressed) == 0:
            self.copper = TextInput(text="",
                                    pos=(350, 250),
                                    background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                                    size = (100, 48))
            copperlbl = Label(text="COPPER",
                            size=(100, 48),
                            pos=(350, 300),
                            color=(255, 255, 255, 1),
                            font_size="15sp")
        else:
            self.copper = TextInput(text="",
                                  pos=(500, 250),
                                  background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                                  size = (100, 48))
            copperlbl = Label(text="COPPER",
                            size=(100, 48),
                            pos=(500, 300),
                            color=(255, 255, 255, 1),
                            font_size="15sp")
        self.add_widget(copperlbl)
        self.add_widget(self.copper)
        l_button_pressed.extend(["Copper"])

def callback3(self, instance):
    if "Zinc" in l_button_pressed:
        pass
    else:
        if len(l_button_pressed) == 0:
            self.zinc = TextInput(text="",
                                  pos=(350, 250),
                                  background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                                  size = (100, 48))
            zinclbl = Label(text="ZINC",
                            size=(100, 48),
                            pos=(350, 300),
                            color=(255, 255, 255, 1),
                            font_size="15sp")
        else:
            self.zinc = TextInput(text="",
                                  pos=(500, 250),
                                  background_color=(1, 1, 1, ),
                                  size = (100, 48))
            zinclbl = Label(text="ZINC",
                            size=(100, 48),
                            pos=(500, 300),
                            color=(255, 255, 255, 1),
                            font_size="15sp")
        self.add_widget(zinclbl)
        self.add_widget(self.zinc)
        l_button_pressed.extend(["Zinc"])
```

The idea of the think is that after having chose 2 differents materials (ex : Zinc & Iron) by clicking on them(buttons), they create a new material (ex : Aluminium), and a new button for this material is create. I hope that my English is good enough for you to understand (I'm french).

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.